# Errors shown near "async" keywords, but build succeeds

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-ctp

When I compile my project without any files opened the build succeeds as expected. Now when I open a file which contains any methods with the **async** keyword, in my errors window appear messages like this:

```
Error   6   ; expected  
Error   10  ; expected  
Error   16  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   
Error   2   Identifier expected
```

When I build the solution, it succeeds, still.

I installed AsyncCTPv3 and the ReSharper. I currently disabled the ReSharper, but still these errors get displayed. Anyone a clue?

edit: The same errors seem to occor near the **await** keywords. I mean await and async go hand in hand, but it's pretty weird that those errors just occur next to **non-.NET-4.0-elements**. And the compiler does not even care a bit. I think just Visual Studio has some trouble to interpret these keywords.

Comment: Seeing the code snippet you're trying to compile would help.  There could be a real syntax error in it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Async CTP v3 Installation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/11/01/async-ctp-v3-installation.aspx)? Have you by any chance installed VS 2011?

Comment: I inserted a code snippet. I never installed VS 2011. I reinstalled VS 2010 SP1 and AsyncCTPv3. @Servy : Our team works with Source Control (TFS) and I'm the only one who faces this issue. And it can't be a syntax error. I get these errors in **every** file which contains methods with async modifiers

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I checked those files. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\msvbide.dll` has the version number of VS2010 SP1 and not of AsyncCTPv3. And I can't the fourth file `My Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples\AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone.dll`. The Folder "Microsoft Visual Studio AsyncCTP" does not even exist. Any solution?

Comment: I would try uninstalling all versions and reinstalling 3 alone, but that is based only on my "standard practice", and not experience with this product.

Comment: The only installed version is v3. As I said, I just reinstalled my machine from scratch one week ago. But I try the reinstall again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all. Lots of thanks to [Joshua Drake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19308/joshua-drake), who provided this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/11/01/async-ctp-v3-installation.aspx). Firstly I recognized that my file versions didn't match up with the ones, which should have been there. I reinstalled without any success. Afterwards I've noticed the following paragraph on this site:

> Run Windows Update before installing Async CTP v3, and get all updates
>   (including Optional updates) from before October 2011
>
> BUT NONE that came after. Three in particular, **KB2635973** and **KB2615527** and **KB2645410**, are known to be **incompatible** with Async CTP
>   v3.
>
> After installing Async CTP v3, then you can get subsequent updates.

That's been the clue. After uninstalling the three mentioned updates, I reinstalled Async CTP again and it worked. Thanks a lot!